# try/catch block can't stop ER_DUP_ENTRY error from crashing my appliction

Tags: mysql, node.js, error-handling, try-catch

Im adding a duplicate to a mysql table and I want to handle elicited *ER_DUP_ENTRY* error comming back with a Try/Catch block but its just crashing anyway , is there any possible way to handle error and stop application from crashing using a try/catch block?

```
async function init() {
    try {
      connection.query(
        'SOME INSERT QUERY',
        (err, result, feilds) => {
          if (err) throw err
          console.log(result);
        }
      );
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }

init();
```

Comment: Does connection.query return a Promise or use a callback? It doesn’t do both

Comment: @AlwaysLearning yeah thats right i guess it does both ,i changed it going with a callback in here yet it doesnt change the origin of the main issues about handeling error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The node mysql-[library](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql) does not support promises out of the box, which means `query` does not return a promise which you can await. So you can either wrap the `query` function in a promise yourself:

```
async function init() {
    try {
        const duplicateResult = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                connection.query(
                    'SOME INSERT QUERY',
                    (err, result, fields) => {
                    if (err) {
                        return reject(err);
                    }
                    resolve(result);
                });
            });

    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}
```

or use `util.promisify` as Always Learning posted alternatively.

Comment: You can't use `try...catch` with callbacks alone - this however should work fine. When using the callback, you need to handle the error in the callback itself.

Comment: Thank @eol its true and did helped .. but i changed it to a call back could you explain why it behave that way when i use a call back i mean , shouldn't a try/catch block catch all throw errors happen within and avoid crashing ?  you might take a look to my edited q

Comment: The try catch block will already have executed once the callback is executed, which is why the error is not caught. You need to handle the error in the callback, i.e. `if (err) // handle error`. I highly recommend reading https://nodejs.dev/the-nodejs-event-loop to understand why this happens :)

Comment: thanks i kinda know how does event loop work but its kinda fuzzy to grasp how does it work in try/catch . so correct me if im wronge... i assume there some kind of function that is being only applied to every statement when they get executed and it now gonna wait for what that statements return . im testing it with setTimeout ... i probably should read more about the mechanism try/catch is working with

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `connection.query` returns `undefined` right away. Your `catch` is not involved because the call ends before the work is done and will call your callback function later. An exception that occurs during your callback is too late. You try/catch block has already completed.

You can use `promisify` to wait on it like this though:

```
const util = require("util");
function init() {
  const queryPromise = util.promisify(connection.query);
  return queryPromise('SOME INSERT QUERY')
    .catch(e => {
      console.log("It failed", e);
    });
  }

init().then(result => {
  if (result) console.log("It worked", result);
  else console.log("Aww, it didn't work");
});
```

Comment: this doesn't work even with a Query expecting to not have an error it has the following error. 
It failed TypeError: Cannot read property 'typeCast' of undefined

Comment: which line gives that error? note that `init()` will always resolve even if the catch inside caught an error since you don't re-throw it, so the `result` could be undefined in that case. You can handle the catch differently and re-throw it, then use `init().then(...).catch(...)` to handle the error.  I edited my answer to show error handling a bit more.

Comment: its probably related to  queryPromise("SOME INESRT QUERY") part ... i share workspace here. 
https://goor.me/ZoXQe